# How to generate sheet from template

Tags: vba, excel

In VBA, i would like create a new sheet from a template after my first sheet.

Example:
In MyFirstSheet i have cell B16="House" and a button "NewSheetFromTemplate". When user click on the button a new sheet generated after my MyFirstSheet and contains same information than TEMPLATE sheet with title House.

My VBA code:

```
Sub NewSheetFromTemplate()
Dim sht As Worksheet
   Set sht = Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy After:=sheets("MyFirstSheet")
   sht.Name = Range("B16").Value
End Sub
```

Excel say me "Syntax error" but why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think is it really necessary to create Worksheet object just to rename it. Try simply like this:

```
Sub NewSheetFromTemplate()
   Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy After:=Sheets("MyFirstSheet")
   ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("MyFirstSheet").Range("B16").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: @Ferfa If you have a new question please post it as such. This question has been answered (as it originally was). Especially new users tend to expand on the original post and successively add more and more questions to it to fulfill their business needs. Yet, that's not the aim of this site. We like to separate here direct and concrete **programming** questions / problems from one another. Furthermore, you would deprive Limak to get more rewards / points for answering more of your questions (and you wouldn't be able to show your appreciation by awarding additional points).

Comment: OK, sorry i am new a this website, i created new post

Comment: Can't see that new post.

Comment: I should wait 90minutes to send new post. If you want you could go in "Revision"  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40038766/revisions)

Comment: @Limak Here is the new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40040785/how-to-generate-sheet-for-each-specific-values

Answer (score 1):

The following line of code does not return an object, one is created but this is not returned to VBA:

```
Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy After:=sheets("MyFirstSheet")
```

This means that you cannot set this line of code to an object. Instead, try something like either of the following two options:

### Using Index

Because you've copied the new worksheet after `Sheets("MyFirstSheet")` you can use the worksheet index of `Sheets("MyFirstSheet")` and then add 1 to get the sheet you've just created.

```
Sub NewSheetFromTemplate()
Dim sht As Worksheet
    Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy After:=sheets("MyFirstSheet")
    Set sht = Sheets(Sheets("MyFirstSheet").Index+1)
    sht.Name = Range("B16").Value
End Sub
```

### Using "Name (2)"

Alternatively, the default name for a copied sheet is the original name with " (2)" tagged onto the end. This is still a useful way of identifying the new worksheet however it could become an issue if the original worksheet has a particularly long name.

```
Sub NewSheetFromTemplate()
Dim sht As Worksheet
    Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy After:=sheets("MyFirstSheet")
    Set sht = Sheets("TEMPLATE (2)")
    sht.Name = Range("B16").Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an instance of a Worksheet via Copy method. Since you know where are you placing the new sheet, you are able to find it after copied, and rename it. You are very close:

```
Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy After:=Sheets("MyFirstSheet")
Sheets(Sheets("MyFirstSheet").Index + 1).Name = Sheets("TEMPLATE").Range("B16").Value
```

Make sure that you have a value in B16 range.

Hope this helps,

Cheers.