# How to generate sheet for each specific values

Tags: vba, excel

I include some code in my project and I have something I do not understand. My `With` loop doesn't works.

My goal is to create new sheet from a specific cell `B16`=House and other new sheet for each cells contains `PRIVATE` word.

Example: 
When user click on button: 
- One new sheet created with title=Value of B16 just after my first sheet (name MyFirstSheet)
- Some other sheets created for each cells values contains word PRIVATE, just after the previous sheet.

So the result will be `MyFirstSheet, House, Test1PRIVATE, Test2PRIVATE`....

```
Sub NewSheetFromTemplate()
Dim SearchRange As Range, c As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet

'New sheet for a specific cell
Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy After:=Sheets("MyFirstSheet")
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("MyFirstSheet").Range("B16").Value

'New sheet for each cell contains PRIVATE
With ThiwWorkbook
   Set SearchRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B16:D70")
   For Each c In SearchRange
      If Right(c.Value, 2) = "PRIVATE" Then
         Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy After:=Sheets("MyFirstSheet")
         Sheets("MyFirstSheet").Name = c.Value
      End If
   Next c
End With
End Sub
```

The problem is: My first sheet is well created (so i have `MyFirstSheet, House,` created) but not others sheet for each cell contains "PRIVATE"
Excel say ERROR 1004, and created a sheet in title TEMPLATE (2)

Comment: You say it doesn't work. What error do you get? When you step through the code, what happens?

Comment: @Ferfa after 1th ciclo of yr loop [code] For Each c In SearchRange [/code] the Sheets("MyFirstSheet") don't exist because you rename it to c.value, then where the new sheet will be copy after ?!?!?!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly then you merely need to change the line

```
If Right(c.Value, 2) = "PRIVATE" Then
```

to

```
If UCase(Right(c.Value, 7)) = "PRIVATE" Then
```

That's because the length of the word "private" is 7 characters and not 2. Furthermore, I am using `UCASE` to ensure that it will also find a match if private is written with different caps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Fabrizio and @Ralph for your assistance and explanation.

My final code:

```
Sub NewSheetFromTemplate()
Dim SearchRange As Range, c As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet

'New sheet for each value contain "PRIVATE"
With ThiwWorkbook
   Sheets(1).Select
   Set SearchRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:C70")
   For Each c In SearchRange
      If Right(c.Value, 7) = "PRIVATE" Then
        Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy After:=ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = c.Value
      End If
   Next c
End With

'New sheet for a specific cell: A2
Sheets(1).Select
Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets(1).Range("A2").Value

'Show OK message
Sheets(1).Select
MsgBox "OK, all sheets well created. Please fill out next sheet"

End Sub
```